# Shell script syntax error: unexpected end of line

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I wrote a simple shell script to check for the existence of a xml file and if it exists, then rename an old xml file to be backup and then move the new xml file to where the old xml file was stored.

```
#!/bin/sh    

oldFile="/Documents/sampleFolder/sampleFile.xml"
newFile="/Documents/sampleFile.xml"
backupFileName="/Documents/sampleFolder/sampleFile2.backup"
oldFileLocation="/Documents/sampleFolder"

if [ -f "$newFile" ] ; then
    echo "File found"
    #Rename old file
    mv $oldFile $backupFileName
    #move new file to old file's location
    mv $newFile $oldFileLocation
else
    echo "File not found, do nothing"
fi
```

However, every time I try to run the script, I get 4 command not found messages and a syntax error: unexpected end of file. Any suggestions on why I get these command not found errors or the unexpected end of file? I double checked that I closed all my double quotes, I have code highlight :)

EDIT: 
    output from running script:

```
: command not found: 
: command not found: 
: command not found1: 
: command not found6: 
replaceXML.sh: line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages? I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: That worked here (with both bash and dash). But you should probably place each variable used on the `mv` between double quotes.

Comment: Your script probably has DOS line endings.

Comment: learn to turn on shell debugging so you can see what is being executed. `set -vx`. Good luck.

Comment: That could be it, I created the shell script in windows and then copied it over to my ubuntu instance in VMWare player to test. I did create another empty shell script, copied the stuff over and the errors disappeared. Now it's not finding the file, but that's another issue :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're running on Cygwin.  There's more to the error messages than what you're seeing:

```
: command not found: 
: command not found: 
: command not found1: 
: command not found6: 
replaceXML.sh: line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

You probably used a Windows editor to create the script file, which means it uses Windows-style CR-LF (`"\r\n"`) line endings, rather than Unix-style LF (`'\n'`) line endings.  Some programs under Cygwin can handle either form, but the shell doesn't.

For example, the line that looks like

```
then
```

looks to the shell like

```
then^M
```

where ^M is the ASCII CR character. This would actually be a valid command name if it existed, but it doesn't, so the shell complains:

```
then^M: command not found
```

But printing the CR character causes the cursor to go back to the beginning of the line, so everthing before the `:` is overwritten.

You're getting the "unexpected end of file" message because the shell never saw a `fi` to match the `if`.

You can use the `dos2unix` command to fix the line endings.  Be sure to read the man page (`man dos2unix`); unlike most text filters, `dos2unix` replaces its input file rather than writing to stdout.

Comment: I didn't even think of cygwin. Good answer.

Comment: If you happen to be running ubuntu 10.04, then there is no `dos2unix`. Instead you would install `tofrodos` using `sudo apt-get install tofrodos` and then run `fromdos` on your file. (ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540180)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see anything wrong with your code apart from then not being in a legal place for older shells. Also notice the quotes around arguments to mv (but that should not be a problem if the files are named properly).

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh    

oldFile="/Documents/sampleFolder/sampleFile.xml"
newFile="/Documents/sampleFile.xml"
backupFileName="/Documents/sampleFolder/sampleFile2.backup"
oldFileLocation="/Documents/sampleFolder"

if [ -f "$newFile" ]
then
    echo "File found"
    mv "$oldFile" "$backupFileName"
    mv "$newFile" "$oldFileLocation"
else
    echo "File not found, do nothing"
fi
```

PS: verify that /bin/sh is (or points to) a bourne based shell.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my case:
I used `Bash On Ubuntu on Windows` (in `Windows 10`) instead of `Cygwin` and then installed `dos2unix` using `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`and used the following command to fix this problem:

```
$ dos2unix < compilelibs.sh > output.sh
```